# API(pre-alpha) link

Tags: discussion, api, hyperlinks

I was looking for the SO API and i found many old posts about this, but i can't find an official document or draft about or any specific page.
It's possible to add the link somewhere to the most official document (or post) about them ?
Maybe just near the FAQ link (only meta) or as FAQ (other sites) or just in the footer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/); private beta at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm still new, it's could be a link to the blog article, the SO network it's huge.

Answer (score 1):

check the blog!

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/